# Monotonicity of Modified Bessel Functions of the Second type

Tags: special-functions, bessel-functions

Given $n\geq1$ an integer, Is it known that 
$$
x\to x^nK_n(x)
$$
is a decreasing function on $(0,\infty)$? I am looking for a reference or a proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[x^{n}K_{n}\left(x\right)\right]=-\frac{1}{2}x^{n-1}\left(xK_{n-1}\left(x\right)-2nK_{n}\left(x\right)+xK_{n+1}\left(x\right)\right)=-x^{n}K_{n-1}\left(x\right).
$$
The claim is thus equivalent to $K_{n}\left(x\right)\geq0$ for all
$n\geq0$ and $0< x<\infty$.